# Is it possible to get documentation for c++ standard library in qcreator

Tags: c++, qt, std, documentation

The documentation in QCreator is good for the Qt framework.

Is it possible to similar documentation for the c++ standard library to integrate with QCreator?

It would be good to be able to just push F1 for documentation and browse a offline documentation.

I expect this to be possible, but have not found information about it.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-help.html has a paragraph about adding external documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but the docs have to be in QCH format.

Look here at [Qt Help Book](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives) and download [this file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/File:qch_book_20190607.zip).

Then unzip the file and follow instructions from Qt [Adding External Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-help.html#adding-external-documentation)

Comment: This allow me to view the documentation, but it does not integrate the same way the Qt documentation does. When holding the cursor over lets say std::map and press F1, then there is no shortcut to the correct page.

Comment: This is the official way to integrate external documentation. Granted, it is more tailored for QtCreator's purposes. I personally use Visual Studio Code - Intellisense is much better at that in it is impartial regarding to sources.

Comment: QtCreator 10 is out with allegedly better support for the STL